# How to submit non English extension to Mozilla Add-ons website?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I have written extension for Firefox, this extension is not in English language.

When uploading extension to Google Chrome gallery I just have to select the language in which the extension is, but when uploading to Mozilla Add-ons website it seems that my extension will automatically fall back to English language.
Is that correct? How can I specify extension language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addons.Mozilla.Org supports falling back to any locale. You need to go to "Edit Add-on Listing" for your add-on and then click Edit for the "Add-on Details" section. There you have a field called "Default Locale" - change it to your preferred fallback language.

If you have trouble finding the field in your language, you can always switch to the English version of Addons.Mozilla.Org (selection field at the bottom right of each page).